# In Flutter, is there a way to click through a page to the page behind it?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a feature that shows a quick, informative popup that will disappear on its own. That part, I can do.

The problem: I want experienced users, who understand the app and don't need the popup, to be able to continue to click the screen and move through the app as though the popup wasn't there.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DashboardScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            // BUTTON 1
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Show popup
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  PageRouteBuilder(
                    opaque: false,
                    pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) {
                      return IgnorePointer(
                        child: Scaffold(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          body: Container(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: const Text('Show Popup'),
            ),

            const SizedBox(height: 20),

            // BUTTON 2
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                print('Button 2 pressed!');
              },
              child: const Text('Print to Console'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, a small red box in the upper left-hand corner represents the popup. I want users to be able to continue to use `Button 2` to print to the console while the red box is on screen. As is, the button is not clickable when the red box is visible.

Does Flutter have a way to pass a click through a page to the page behind it? I assumed this could be accomplished with the `IgnorePointer` widget; however, this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your example code doesn't work is because `PageRouteBuilder`, along with all other included subclasses of `ModalRoute`, installs a barrier to block pointer events. You can change how that barrier is built by creating a subclass that overrides `buildModalBarrier`. So you want that method to return a widget that closes the modal on tap while also allowing widgets behind it to actually handle the tap.

Unfortunately Flutter's gesture system really doesn't like to allow multiple gesture detectors to respond to a single input. The only thing I found that worked was a `Listener` with `onPointerUp` set to dismiss the modal route. Using anything else like a `GestureDetector` or even just using `Listener.onPointerDown` prevented the buttons behind the modal from operating.

Here is the final code for the new route:

```dart
class TransparentDialogRoute extends DialogRoute {
  TransparentDialogRoute({
    required super.context,
    required super.builder,
  });

  @override
  Widget buildModalBarrier() {
    return Listener(
      behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
      onPointerUp: (_) => navigator?.maybePop(),
    );
  }
}
```

And [here is a Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=710fc238a54f3f5fb8064f1b6fe83b23) with that route incorporated into your example code.

Comment: Thank you! This is almost exactly what I am looking for. I don't want the user to close the popup with a tap, I want it to be a timed exit; so, changing the `buildModalBarrier` to return `SizedBox.shrink()` and then programmatically popping the page with a timer is the right fix for me. Thank you for getting me to the right outcome!